# Is it possible to perform Deduplication recursively?

Tags: compression, deduplication

If anybody is familiar with the concept of Deduplication (If not,read link on wikipedia)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_deduplication

Is it possible to perform Deduplication recursively i.e. Deduplicate deduplicated data ?
  It might lead to lower savings in terms of space but surely at a very large scale it could lead to some savings in terms of a few Gbs ?

Are we concerned about Data Integrity ? (Not being able to assure when brought back to its original form it will be an exact copy of the original)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your deduplication is done based on some sort of fixed sized data blocks, then no, further deduplication is useless since you already save each identical block only once. (Blocks can be any kind of logical blocks that might or might not map directly to hardware blocks)

If your recursive deduplication scheme uses a different block size or if you use a non-fixed block size, recursive deduplication might work and might lead to further savings (in theory).

It is hard to say if any of todays software would support this. My best guess would be [ZFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS). There you can create storage pools that use normal files as storage device. These normal files could themself be stored on a ZFS system where deduplication is turned on. Now you would have recursive deduplication. (with really bad performance)

The obvious question is: *What will save more space?* Recursive deduplication or Compression+Deduplication. And: will deduplication of compressed+deduplicated data save anything?

Comment: Well Said. I wanted to confirm that :)